# Break error on cout

Tags: c++, visual-studio

I'm writing an easy Game Of Life simulator. Everything works smoothly except at the very end, when the result is printed by cout I get a break error. I don't understand why and I would like to ask for your help.

variables

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

struct cell
{
    bool isAlive;
    int posX;
    int posY;
    int numberOfAliveNeighbours;
    char group;
};
int cellNumber;
cell *cellTable = new cell[cellNumber];
int numberOfTunrs;
```

main:

```
int main()
{
        int x;
        int y;
        int cellCounter = 0;
        cin >> x >> y;
        cellNumber = x*y;
        cin >> numberOfTunrs;
        for (int i = 0; i < x; i++)
        {
            for (int j = 0; j < y; j++)
            {
                char cellAliveChar;
                cin >> cellAliveChar;
                if (cellAliveChar == '#')
                {
                    cellTable[cellCounter].isAlive = true;

                }
                else if (cellAliveChar == '.')
                {
                    cellTable[cellCounter].isAlive = false;

                }
                cellTable[cellCounter].numberOfAliveNeighbours = 0;
                cellTable[cellCounter].group = '#';
                cellTable[cellCounter].posX = j;
                cellTable[cellCounter].posY = i;
                cellCounter++;

            }
        }

        doTurns(x, y);
        int result;
        result = countGroups();
        **cout << result << endl;**
        //here is breakpoint 
        cin >> x;


}
```

countGroups (idk if it's relevant):

```
int countGroups()
{
    int max = 0;
    int current;
    int i = 0;
    char checkingGroup = 'A';
    do
    {
        current = 0;
        for (int j = 0; j < cellNumber; j++)
        {
            if (cellTable[j].group == checkingGroup + i)
            {
                current++;
            }
        }
        i++;
        if (current > max)
        {
            max = current;
        }
    } while (current != 0);

    return max;

}
```

the breakpoint screenshot:

[Click to view the screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vC1Lh.png)

Comment: `**cout << result << endl;**` why ?, did you mean `cout << result << endl;` if you already did a using namespace std or `std::cout << result << std::endl; `

Comment: `} while (current = 0);` should be `} while (0 == current);` or some proper condition. Also it is not clear what `cellTable` is and what happens inside of `doTurns` most likely some sort of buffer overrun corrupting program state.

Comment: @VTT Hi I added the global variables and edited it. The brekpoint still occurs though :(

Comment: @xanadev yes i just wanted to mark where the breakpoint occurs in the code :) I edited my post and added variables and includes, I am using namespace std, you might want to check

Answer (score 1):

The problem is `cellTable` declaration:

```
int cellNumber;
cell *cellTable = new cell[cellNumber];
```

Global variables are implicitly initialized with 0 so `cellNumber` will point to array of 0 size and any attempt to access `cellTable` items leads to undefined behavior.

It would be better to make all variables local and pass them to functions explicitly. Instead of manually allocating array you should use `std::vector`, or at least allocate after assigning an appropriate number to `cellNumber` (after getting `x` and `y` values).